# e.Data.GetDataPresent not working in WinForms drag-and-drop handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag files into my application from a program called Locate32 (which is great by the way).  Here is what happens:

```
e.Data.GetFormats()
{string[7]}
    [0]: "FileDrop"
    [1]: "FileNameW"
    [2]: "FileName"
    [3]: "FileNameMap"
    [4]: "FileNameMapW"
    [5]: "Shell IDList Array"
    [6]: "Shell Object Offsets"
DataFormats.FileDrop
"FileDrop"
e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)
false
```

Why does `e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)` return `false` even though FileDrop is clearly one of the formats listed as "available"?

If I do `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)` I get a list of a bunch of filenames, as I should.  Also, drag and drop works fine from Windows Explorer.

Here's the code for my DragEnter handler:

```
private void MyForm_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    } else {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your OS version?  And have you stepped through this with a debugger to see if your `DragEnter` event is being raised at all?

Comment: This happens in XP and Win7.  Yes, it is being raised - the first block I posted is me breaking on the first line of `MyForm_DragEnter` and doing some things in the immediate window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look into [e.AllowedEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.allowedeffect.aspx) if `DragDropEffects.Copy` is within the list.

#### Update

Some time ago i also had some problems with getting the right format out of the `GetDataPresent()`. Due to this fact, i just looked directly into the list provided by `GetFormats()` and did it on myself. The code was something like that:

```
private void OnItemDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the first format out of the list and try to cast it into the
    //desired type.
    var list = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as IEnumerable<ListViewItem>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
```

This simple solution works for me, but you could also walk all over the `GetFormats()` array with linq and try to find your desired type by [`IEnumerable<T>.OfType<MyType>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) or something similar.

Comment: Yes, `e.AllowedEffect` "contains" `DragDropEffects.Copy` for both Locate32 and Windows Explorer. The issue is an apparent mismatch between `e.Data.GetDataPresent()` and `e.Data.GetFormats()`.  I tried looking in Reflector but I really don't understand what's going on in there.

Comment: Since your update is close to what I'm doing now, I'll accept your solution.  However, I don't see any need to try and grab all the data until it's actually needed (i.e. in the DragDrop event handler).

Comment: I was utterly confused by GetDataPresent and was convinced it would work in much the same way as IsAssignableFrom....So, if you have a control which is composed of items from the same hierarchy you'll need to perform checks on each type as far as I can tell...No polymorphism here...

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone can tell me why this is a bad idea, here's what I'm going to go with:

```
private void MyForm_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    e.Effect = (e.Data.GetFormats().Any(f => f == DataFormats.FileDrop)
        ? DragDropEffects.Copy
        : DragDropEffects.None);
}
```

Works from both Windows Explorer and Locate32.